# To make 2virtual machines communicate, I have reviewed all the configuration steps using vbox. I dont have file>pref>network opt in vbox.Any insights?

Tags: virtual-machine

To add a Nat network in virtual box, the file>preferences>network is not available in the virtual box windows version I use.

Is there any specific version of virtual box available for the query I asked? Because I'm looking to make 2 vm's communicate.